# Feasibility of choosing EC2 + Docker as a production deployment option

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, microservices

I am trying to deploy my microservice in EC2 machine. I already launched my EC2 machine with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS AMI. And also I found that we can install Docker and run containers through Docker installation. Also I tried sample service deployment using Docker in my Ubuntu. I successfully run commands using -d option for running image in background also.

Can I choose this EC2 + Docker for deployment of my microservice for actual production environment? Then I can deploy all my Spring Boot microservice in this option.

I know that ECS is another option for me.To be frank trying to avoid ECR, ECS optimized AMI and its burdens, Looking for machine with full control that only belongs to me.

But still I need to know about the feasibility of choosing EC2 + Docker through my Ubuntu machine. Also I am planning to deploy my Angular 2 app. I don't need to install, deploy and manage any application server for both Spring Boot and Angular, since it will gives me about a serverless production environment.

Comment: I'm not sure why you assume using ECS dictates that you no longer have full control of your instance. If you're not running some orchestration of your own (e.g., kubernetes), I _highly_ recommend taking advantage of ECS features - especially for a production deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is a "traditional" single server environment and does not have much in common with a microservices deployment. However keep in mind that this may be OK if it is only you, or a small team working on the whole application. The microservices architectural style was introduced to be able to handle huge, complex applications with large development teams that require to scale out immensely due to fast business growth. Here an [example story from Uber](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/uber-darwin).

Please read [this](https://martinfowler.com/microservices/) for more information about how and why the microservices architectural style was introduced as well as the benefits/drawbacks. Now about your question:

> "Can I choose this EC2 + Docker for deployment of my microservice for actual production environment? "

Your question can be simply answered: You can, but it is probably not a good idea assuming you have a large enough project to require a microservices architecture.

You would have to implement all of the following deployment aspects yourself, which is typically covered by an orchestration system, like [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/):

1. Service Discovery and Load Balancing
2. Horizontal Scaling
3. Multi-Container Application Deployment
4. Container Health-Management / Self-Healing
5. Virtual Networking
6. Rolling Updates
7. Storage Orchestration

> "Since It will gives me about a serverless production environment to
>   me."

EC2 is by definition not serverless, of course. You will have to maintain your EC2 instances, including OS updates, security patches etc. And if you only have a single server you will have service outages because of it.

Comment: Ok Sir. Thank you for your response and spending time for my confusion. This is new information for me. But i would like to clarify that this service discovery & routing also going to implement in my microservice by using spring boot + spring cloud tools(Eureka discovery ,Zuul proxy server , Ribbon load balancing etc..from java) Those are also providing these , but in microservice form. Also I readed that about docker swarm. Kubernetes is alternative to swarm ? Swarm is different one? Let me know about this, I am facing lot of confusions since I am beginner in services and container world.

Comment: Yes, Docker Swarm is an alternative to kubernetes in terms of container orchestration. I'd recommend to download a minikube and just playing with container deployment configurations to get a better feeling of what these systems do.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it. I have had Docker on standard EC2 instances running without problem. By "my microservice" you mean a single microservice, right?

You don't need service discovery or routing rules?

Comment: No. In my project 20 to 30 microservices are there. I need to create separate container for all. And need to run every container.That scenario i need to know.Any way thank you for your response Mr. Carlos.

Comment: I also looking for spring cloud - Like Zureka service , Zuul proxy server and hystrix as my spring cloud services.

Comment: In that case you need to solve the routing for each microservice. You can do it by yourself using a proxy that routes to different port depending on route. In any case ECS and AWS Application Load Balancer does it pretty good. I don't know Spring ecosistem (I'm php guy...) but what you need should be language agnostic.

Comment: I already tested the scenario using by uploading image into ECR and successfully working.Already used Optimized AMI for that.No issue with that. But I am finding in my own EC2 plus Docker for production version for microservice.

Comment: Then you can use Nginx or Varnish to emulate the ELB routing to your services. You define router patterns and then proxy them to the correct port (if all the services are in the same machine) or to the correct host:port if the microservices are distributed. Could become pretty difficult to maintain.

Comment: yes sir, I will explore that section in your previous comment, since all services are in same machine. Currently I only tested using sample service.I only need to confirm that this approach ( EC2 + Docker) is suitable for my actual project production. That is my worry. Is there any problem for this approach , let me know that.Can I continue this in production version also?

Comment: As said before I had docker on plain EC2 instances running in production environments with no problems, so IMHO its feasible. By the way now that apps are running on ECS.

Comment: Ok Sir . Thank you for your guidance and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I choose this EC2 + Docker for deployment of my microservice for actual production environment?

Yes, this is totally possible, although I suggest using **kubernetes** as the container-orchestrator as it manages the lifecycle of the containers for you:

1. [Running Kubernetes on AWS EC2](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/)
2. [Amazon Elastic Container Service for Kubernetes](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-elastic-container-service-for-kubernetes/)
3. [Manage Kubernetes Clusters on AWS Using Kops](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/kubernetes-clusters-aws-kops/)
4. [Amazon EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/)

Comment: Ok Sir. Thank you for your response and spending time for my confusion. I would like to ask about Docker swarm is an alternative to this kubernetes? Or is it providing different functionality other than kubernetes? Can you clarify because, After seeing your comment I also found docker swarm?

Comment: @Jacob Glad to help. Upvote and accept my answer if you think it is useful so that others know this is the right answer, thanks! More information about Docker Swarm is at https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/. It is a container orchestrator.